# Number of particles needed when equilibrium energy is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

N particles obeying classical statistics are distributed among three states having $\epsilon_0=0$, $\epsilon_1=k_BT$ and $\epsilon_2=2k_BT$. If the total equilibrium energy of the system is $1000k_BT$, what is the value of N?

My take: I tried summation of $n_i\epsilon_i$ but to no yield.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classically the particles are distributed according to the Maxwell distribution, $$n(\varepsilon) = n_0 e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{k_B T}},$$ where $n_0$ is some normalization constant. So you have a first equation $$n(\varepsilon_0)+n(\varepsilon_1)+n(\varepsilon_2)=N,$$ which allows to you find $n_0$ in terms of $N$ and $$\varepsilon_0 n(\varepsilon_0)+\varepsilon_1 n(\varepsilon_1)+\varepsilon_2 n(\varepsilon_2)=E,$$ which allows you to find $n_0$ in terms of $E$.